# Apply different css styling to words next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want to put different words together in a `<div>`, and each word has a different `font-size` and a different CSS styling.

I can manage the different font-sizes, but somehow the words are ordered in a list with line-height. This I do not want.

This is my code:

```
<p style="font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff;">more hungry?</p><p style="font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff;">want a drink too?</p><p style="font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff;">have it with natural flavour?</p><p style="font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff;">eat atleast 2 pieces of fruit?</p><p style="font-size: 8px; color: #ffffff;">a snack every hour?</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

They're on seperate lines because `<p>` are block line elements.

One solution would be to change the style of those `<p>` elements to `inline-block`:

```
p {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

(You should probably give all `<p>` elements you want to target a common class and use that as the selector instead, as the above targets all `<p>`'s).

Or just use `<span>` elements instead (they're inline by default):

```
<span style="font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff;">more hungry?</span><span style="font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff;">want a drink too?</span><span style="font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff;">have it with natural flavour?</span><span style="font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff;">eat atleast 2 pieces of fruit?</span><span style="font-size: 8px; color: #ffffff;">a snack every hour?</span>
```

Note though that inline CSS is generally not advised - you should use an external style sheet instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the whole section in a `<p>` tag and then use a create a span for each different style you'd like to have? This would be a lot of spans with classes, though it seems to be a fairly common way that folks do this.

Here's a possibility (utilizing the "best practice" of separating content and style):

```
<style>
p {color: #ffffff;}
span.1 {font-size: 11px;}
span.2 {font-size: 15px;}
span.3 {font-size: 13px;}
span.4 {font-size: 20px;}
span.5 {font-size: 8px;}
</style>    


<p><span class="1">More hungry?</span> <span class="2">want a drink too?</span> <span class="3">have it with natural flavour?</span> <span class="5">eat at least 2 pieces of fruit?</span> <span class="6">a snack every hour?</span></p>
```

I'd recommend naming the span classes to something that was a bit more descriptive. But this should do the trick, depending on the particular use you have in mind.